# Can I move this IKEA Pax storage system connector piece?

Tags: storage

I'm living in a place with an IKEA Pax storage system installed by previous owner. I'd like to adjust the shelves to where I need them to be. However, this connector piece blocks one of the places I want to place shelf.

Has anyone seen this thing and know what it does? (I'm guessing it's supporting the vertical plank but I'd like to make sure.) Can it be moved to a slightly lower place on the same planks?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Imagine it can.  Looks like a corner block to hold the two pieces together, maybe also to hold a shelf up.  A few inches up or down should not mater and you can probably put it in straight.  Pilot holes in new place before the screws will help.

Comment: @crip659 , that is good for an answer. Its the answer I would give

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a simple corner block/connector to hold two pieces together.  If so then it's position is not that important, a few inches up or down will not matter.

What might matter is if it also is holding up the shelf/top above it.  If just holding a shelf that you want to move anyway, then no problem as long as the other three blocks are moved the same distance.

Remove the screws and measure to the place you want it moved to.  Drill pilot holes for the screws and remount the blocks in the new places.  You might need to hold the two pieces together when moving the blocks, with clamps, tape, or a helper.